# Intersection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

> Give examples of the following with justification. A collection of open subsets $(U_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$ is not open.

as far as I'm aware the intersection of finitely many open sets is open, however, I'm assuming the fact I'm working in $\mathbb{R}$ is key in this question?

Comment: Not really, except that you’re being asked specifically for an example in $\Bbb R$. You could equally well use $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb R^n$, or many, many other spaces.

Comment: Not exactly. Such an example can be found in any topological space.

Comment: @Stromael No, not in any topological space. In, for instance, the trivial or the discrete topology on some set, any intersection of open sets is open.

Comment: @Stromael no, there are topological spaces with the property that the open sets are closed under arbitrary unions. Discrete and indiscrete ones for example, but also many other spaces.

Comment: @Arthur Ah, of course, apologies. I wonder how one might characterise all spaces for which such an example can be found.

Comment: @Stromael It's at least true in any space where all open sets are also closed, but that's most likely not a complete characterization.

Comment: @Stromael Spaces in which any intersection of open sets is open are called [Alexandrov spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology). Alexandrov topologies on a set are in one-to-one correspondence with preorders on the same set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of *finitely many* open sets is open, this is part of the general definition of open sets. Infinitely many, though, is a different story. Take $U_n = \left(-\frac1n,\frac{1}{n}\right)$, for instance. The intersection of all of these is just $\{0\}$, which is not open.

There's nothing really special about $\Bbb R$ in this case. In some spaces you cannot find examples of such $U_n$, but in very many spaces you can.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just $\Bbb R$, it's the fact that the space is $T_1$ without isolated points. This means that if $a$ is any point, then $R_a=\Bbb R\setminus\{a\}$ is a dense open set.

Now if $A$ is *any* set, then $A=\bigcap_{b\notin A}R_b$. In particular, if $A$ is not open, then this is an intersection of open sets which is not open again. And if $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is a countable set, it is a countable intersection.

You can probably try and find other conditions on $\Bbb R$ which imply this. Not just being $\Bbb R$ itself. Note, on the other hand, that in the discrete topology every intersection of open sets is an open set; as well in the trivial topology!

Answer (score 1):

$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N^+}\left(-1-\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right)=[-1,1]$$
$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N^+}\left(-\infty,\frac1n\right)=(-\infty,0]$$
*Finitely* many open sets must have open intersections. This is infinitely many sets.